# Why is vertical traversal faster than horizontal traversal when it should be the opposite?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

So I am doing the scala parallel programming course, which challenged us to implement the box blur using different implementations.

One of them is to chunk the image by rows and another is to chunk the image by columns. The image is stored as (row major order) :

```
  type RGBA = Int  

  /** Image is a two-dimensional matrix of pixel values. */
  class Img(val width: Int, val height: Int, private val data: Array[RGBA]) {
    def this(w: Int, h: Int) = this(w, h, new Array(w * h))

    def apply(x: Int, y: Int): RGBA = {
      data(y * width + x)
    }

    def update(x: Int, y: Int, c: RGBA): Unit = data(y * width + x) = c
  }
```

This is the implementation of basic blur, which is same in all implementations.

```
  def boxBlurKernel(src: Img, x: Int, y: Int, radius: Int): RGBA = {
    val pixels = for {
      j <- (y - radius to y + radius)
      i <- (x - radius to x + radius)
      if (i > 0 && i < src.width && j > 0 && j < src.height)
    } yield src(i,j)

    val reds = pixels.map(red)
    val greens = pixels.map(green)
    val blues = pixels.map(blue)
    val alphas = pixels.map(alpha)

    val redComponent = reds.sum / pixels.size
    val greenComponent = greens.sum / pixels.size
    val blueComponent = blues.sum / pixels.size
    val alphaComponent = alphas.sum / pixels.size

    rgba(redComponent,greenComponent,blueComponent,alphaComponent)
  }
```

Now we implement a vertical blur implementation -

```
def blur(src: Img, dst: Img, from: Int, end: Int, radius: Int): Unit = {

    val imageHeight = src.height

    val xCoordinates: Seq[Int] = from until end
    val yCoordinates: Seq[Int] = 0 until imageHeight

    for {
      xCoordinate <- xCoordinates
      yCoordinate <- yCoordinates
    } yield dst.update(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, boxBlurKernel(src, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, radius))

  }

  def parBlur(src: Img, dst: Img, numTasks: Int, radius: Int): Unit = {

    val imageWidth = src.width
    val boundaries = linspace(0, imageWidth, numTasks + 1).map(_.toInt).toScalaVector.sliding(2)
    val tasks = boundaries.toList.map { case Seq(from, end) => task {
      blur(src, dst, from, end, radius)
    }
    }
    tasks.foreach(_.join())
  }
```

And then we implement Horizontal blur

```
  def blur(src: Img, dst: Img, from: Int, end: Int, radius: Int): Unit = {
    val imageWidth = src.width

    val xCoordinates = 0 until imageWidth
    val yCoordinates = from until end

    for {
      yCoordinate <- yCoordinates
      xCoordinate <- xCoordinates
    } yield dst.update(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, boxBlurKernel(src, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, radius))
  }

def parBlur(src: Img, dst: Img, numTasks: Int, radius: Int): Unit = {
    val imageHeight = src.height
    val boundaries = linspace(0, imageHeight, numTasks + 1).map(_.toInt).toScalaVector.sliding(2)

    boundaries.toList.map {
      case Seq(from: Int, end: Int) => task(from, end, blur(src, dst, from, end, radius))
    }.foreach(_.join())

  }
```

Now since the Image is stored in row major format, it was expected that Horizontal blur utilizes the processor cache more efficiently and should be somewhat faster than Vertical blur timings.
However, I find opposite results.

Vertical box blur time -

```
[info] Running (fork) scalashop.VerticalBoxBlurRunner 
fork/join blur time: 2281.5884644 ms
```

Horizontal box blur time -

```
[info] Running (fork) scalashop.HorizontalBoxBlurRunner 
fork/join blur time with number of tasks = 32: 2680.8516574 ms
```

I'm running these benchmarks with `scalameter` and on Mac OS 2.2 GHz
The `task` parallel primitive is returning a ForkJoinTask inturn.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will depend on a range of factors, including the size of the image, the size of the kernel, the architecture of the processor, and the efficiency of the JIT compiler.

In this case `boxBlurKernel` is very inefficient because it uses at least 9 loops when the computation could be done in a single pass. It also clips the coordinates each time rather than clipping the bounds before entering the loop.

It is seems unlikely that the difference is due to caching because such a small portion of the code is reading new data into the cache. The number of loops makes it very hard for the JIT compiler to optimise the code, and the difference may simply be that it generate more efficient code in the second case.

Using multiple tasks complicates things, so it would be better to test with a single task to see which version is actually more efficient. After that, work on the overall efficiency of the algorithm before worrying about the relative efficiency of two different versions.